# Joining my armatures makes my meshes "vanish"

Tags: rigging

Beginner rigger question:

I have 5 armatures, 4 Legs and 1 future parent armature.

So i select all legs, then shift-select the parent armature, press CTRL-J and....

parts of my meshes are gone.

So it looks like i am making a very trivial mistake here?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because inside armatures bones have equal names. Then you join armatures, blender renames bones because it should have unique names in one armature, so that links gets broken. Consider going through all of them and give a unique name instead "Bone", "Bone.001" and "Bone.002". You can do this by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> in edit mode

Comment: perfect, thank you!