# how to make bone names unique for several (selected armatures)?

Tags: rigging

This is a follow-up question to:

[Joining my armatures makes my meshes "vanish"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273590/joining-my-armatures-makes-my-meshes-vanish)

I have learnt that meshes with the same bone names "vanish" if you join armatures. Is there any function or add-on that makes all bone names unique for selected armatures?

Because my typical workflow building a robot is:

- rigging one leg
- parent that to an armature
- copy that leg + armature

-> and then i have double names and cannot "join" them because of same bone names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select one armature and go to pose mode or edit mode, select all bones, press F3 and search for Batch Rename.

Make sure to choose "Bones" as target, then you can choose "Set Name" option, "Prefix" Method and add something like "Rig_01_" to all bone names.

If the model is alredy skinned, every corresponding vertex group will be renamed too.

[image]